# What's the recommended way to write Serilog logs to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, serilog

I'm looking to use Serilog to write structured log data to an Amazon S3 bucket, then analyze using Databricks.  I assumed there would be an S3 sink for Serilog but I found I was wrong.  I think perhaps using the File sink along with something else might be the ticket, but I'm unsure what that might look like.  I suppose I could mount the S3 bucket on my EC2 instance and write to it, but I'm told that's problematic.  Could one of you fine folks point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

I would now recommend to use [Serilog.Sinks.AmazonS3](https://github.com/SeppPenner/Serilog.Sinks.AmazonS3) which was created for exactly the scenario described.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the project :)

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, there are no Sinks that write to Amazon S3, so you'd have to write your own.

I'd start by taking a look at the [`Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage`](https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage) sink, as it probably can serve as a base for you to write a sink for Amazon S3.

Links to the source code for several other sinks are available in the wiki and can give you some more ideas too: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks